# c# Android - Find object by color on bitmap

Tags: c#, android, algorithm, colors, bitmap

I would like to find an object on a bitmap using its HSV color. I know there already are some topics created about this issue, but they seem not to work on Android (I didn't find System.Drawing.Imaging on Android) or to be less efficient than the algorithm I already created:

```
public Rect FindObjectOnBitmap(Bitmap bm)
{
    bm.GetPixels(pixels, 0, bm.Width, 0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height);
    // Get the matching pixels.
    for(int x = 0; x<bm.Width; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < bm.Height; y++)
        {
            Color color = new Color(pixels[x + bm.Width * y]);
            pixelsMatch[x,y] = (color.GetBrightness() > Settings.Tracker.blackFilter && color.GetSaturation() > Settings.Tracker.whiteFilter) && (Angle(Settings.Tracker.hue, color.GetHue()) < Settings.Tracker.sensitivity);
        }
    Rect objectRect = null;
    int maxNbPixel = 0;
    // for each matching pixel
    for (int x = 0; x < bm.Width; x ++)
        for (int y = 0; y < bm.Height; y ++)
            if(pixelsMatch[x, y])
            {
                int nbPixel = 0;
                Rect objectRectTemp = new Rect(x, y, x, y);
                Queue<Pixel> zone = new Queue<Pixel>();
                zone.Enqueue(new Pixel(x, y));
                while(zone.Count != 0)
                {
                    Pixel px = zone.Dequeue();
                    nbPixel++;
                    // Updates object position
                    if (px.x < objectRectTemp.Left)
                        objectRectTemp.Left = px.x;
                    if (px.x > objectRectTemp.Right)
                        objectRectTemp.Right = px.x;
                    if (px.y < objectRectTemp.Bottom)
                        objectRectTemp.Bottom = px.y;
                    if (px.y > objectRectTemp.Top)
                        objectRectTemp.Top = px.y;
                    // for each nearby pixel
                    for (int side = 0; side < 4; side++)
                    {
                        Pixel sidePx = px.Side(side);
                        if (sidePx.x >= 0 && sidePx.x < bm.Width && sidePx.y >= 0 && sidePx.y < bm.Height)
                        {
                            if (pixelsMatch[sidePx.x, sidePx.y])
                            {
                                zone.Enqueue(sidePx);
                                pixelsMatch[sidePx.x, sidePx.y] = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Save the object if it is big enough.
                if(nbPixel > maxNbPixel && nbPixel >= 4)
                {
                    maxNbPixel = nbPixel;
                    objectRect = objectRectTemp;
                }
            }
    return objectRect;
}
// Function comparing hues.
static float Angle(float deg1, float deg2)
{
    if (Math.Abs(deg1 - deg2) > 180f)
        return (360f - Math.Abs(deg1 - deg2));
    else
        return Math.Abs(deg1 - deg2);
}
```

However, I am reading a stream, and this algorithm is also not efficient enough since I get 0.1 fps on a 640x480 image... I get a good fps only if I create the bitmap with a smaller resolution than the real image (for example 40x30). That enables me to detect big or close objects with a bad precision (position and size).

How can I increase the efficiency enough, knowing I am on an ANDROID device...

Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry for my poor English ^^